# Converting a date formatted string to be used as a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this code

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Which gives an output like this:  20160815085427

I would like to use that output as the string 20160815085427
something like this

myDateNumberString = thatString

How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean NSString *myString= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] ?

Comment: What I want to do is to create a string object myDateNumberString with that output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same expression you are using in NSLog in a variable.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *myDateNumberString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDa‌​te date]];
NSLog(@"%@", myDateNumberString);
```